# Apache2 está retornando un error 403 (prohibido)

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

Estoy intentando habilitar un sitio en Apache en mi servidor Ubuntu 14.04 con PHP 5 habilitado, pero al parecer incluso siguiendo los pasos indicados en este hilo de Stackoverflow y después de navegar incluso por la red de Stackoverflow estadounidense no he encontrado una solución a mis problemas.

He seguido uno y cada paso tales como dar los permisos correctos al directorio `/home` y más.

Archivo de configuración VHost:

```
<Directory /home/web/site.site.com>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag register_globals off
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /home/web/site.site.com
  ServerName site.kenygamer.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.site.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.site.com/privkey.pem

  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <Location />
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
      RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
    </Location>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Un dato curioso es que inclusive si el archivo (URI) la que estoy visitando no existe, sigue retornando un error 403 en vez de retornar un error no encontrado (404).

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente he encontrado la solución para este molesto problema. Basta revisar el log de error localizado en `/var/log/apache2/error.log` para entender lo que pasaba.

Para quienes estén teniendo un problema similar incluso habiendo dado los permisos correctos al directorio casa o raíz, simplemente añadan dentro de la directiva del directorio en su VHost la siguiente línea:

```
Require all granted
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.